# How to use Fiddler's Root Certificate Authority in FiddleCore?

Tags: c#, windows, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

I would like to load the Root CA generated by Fiddler in FiddleCore to be use to sign HTTPS certificates on the fly. My reason for doing this is to be able to switch between Fiddler and FiddlerCore on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

First the `fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert` and `fiddler.certmaker.bc.key` pref values in Fiddler are obtained by typing `about:config` in the QuickExec bar.

Afterwards in FiddlerCore (before starting the proxy) they are applied:

```
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", FIDDLER_KEY);
Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", FIDDLER_CERT);
```